# Leaf variety in sapling addon?

Tags: texturing, add-on, sapling-addon

I'm using the Sapling addon in 2.79, and I'm having trouble making the leaves look realistic.  As you can see in the screenshot (sorry for the forest HDRI in the background; I know it made the image a little obscured) every leaf is exactly the same, top and bottom, all the same size, straight, etc.  What I am wondering is if the following is possible:

1. Curved leaves
2. Leaves of varied sizes
3. Some leaves with one texture, other leaves with another texture (i.e. orange, red, brown, yellow for fall trees)
4. Ability to add bottom textures

All this is assuming you didn't convert it to a mesh and had to do all this leaf by leaf :)

Thanks, I really hope others can benefit from this post too!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these I know for a fact are possible. The Leaf Object parameter answers 3 of your 4 questions. First, you'll need to create a leaf, either with a Nurbs Surface, or a simple mesh (either method will work, but if you plan on texturing the top and bottom differently, I'd go with a mesh). Then when you add your Sapling Curve, in the Leaves settings, set the Leaf Shape to "DupliFaces" and the Leaf Object to the name of the mesh you created to be your leaf. The varied leaf sizes has its own parameter toward the bottom right "Leaf Scale Variation". Unfortunately, the Leaf Object parameter doesn't allow you to add Groups of objects, but you may be able to use the a particle system instead to achieve color variation in your leaves. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Amazing!  It worked!  Thanks so much.  The only issue though that remains is that I can't seem to make the leaves work with multiple objects...to get that variety of fall colours